# how to remove overflow menu from option button in Android

Tags: android

i was trying to make the custom overflow button with new drawable source start an activity instead of showing drop down menu. I've read somewhere that I have to make sure there's only one item in onOptionItemSelected, so here's my code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logout_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(PetVacActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

but unfortunately, my app still showing the overflow button, but there's only one blank drop down menu like this

[image]
instead of directly start my activity, i have to click the dropdown menu first to activate my intent

Comment: are you using toolbar ?

Comment: menu xml : android:showAsAction="ifRoom" on all items

Comment: @Arslan yes, i tried hideoverflowmenu() but the drop down still visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally get it working! I only had to change "android:showAsAction" to "app:showAsAction".
Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 3):

In menu.xml u can add

```
android:showAsAction=""
```

with these values

```
never,ifRoom,always,withText,collapseActionView
```

you can use them in | combinations.

in you case you can use

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>`

Comment: finally get it working! I only had to change "android:showAsAction" to "app:showAsAction"

Answer (score 0):

Just call hideoverflowMenu function of toolbar like this.

```
toolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use submenu and with own icon

```
SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("MyOverflow").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_overflow);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(subMenu.getItem(), MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
MenuItem menuItem = subMenu.add("SubMenuItem1");
MenuItem menuItem2 = subMenu.add("SubMenuItem1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these two:

1. Using the menu defined in an xml file

Menu xml file named 'my_menu' (using the appcompat library):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/log_out_menu_item"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_log_out"
          android:title=""
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.log_out_menu_item:
            // start new activity here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

2. Adding the menu item by code

Activity code:

```
private static final int LOG_OUT_MENU_ITEM_ID = 1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, LOG_OUT_MENU_ITEM_ID, 0, "");
    menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_actionbar);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case LOG_OUT_MENU_ITEM_ID:
            // start new activity here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```